# How to use ng-bind on a td tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following `<td>` element

```
<td translate="Price-{{product-op}} {{product-np}}" translate-values=GetVal()></td>
```

Now, `GetVal()` function is potentially dangerous because it is in a third party app.

So, I have decided to strip off any malicious elements. Decided to use `ng-bind`

The problem is how to ng-bind and then translate in the above code?

I came up with something like,

```
<td ng-bind translate="Price-{{product-op}} {{product-np}}" translate-values=GetVal()></td>
```

but it throws angular exception.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What kind of exception does it throw?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Angular Translate library (https://angular-translate.github.io), the `translate` directive should bind the value automatically. If you remove the `ng-bind`, it should work.

But I am not sure what library you are using for your translations, so my suggestion might not help you. You might have to provide more information.

Also `ng-bind` requires a value in the `$scope` - for example put `$scope.myValue = 'My Value'` in your controller and then use this in your HTML `<td ng-bind="myValue"></td>`. But again, I do not know what the `translate` directive is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understood exactly what do you want to do, But I imagine that the exception is because the 'ng-bind' prop needs a value to do a bind like this:

```
<script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.name = 'Whirled';
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Enter name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></label><br>
  Hello <span ng-bind="name"></span>!
</div>
```